# create a new variable for each loop in a foreach-loop

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

How can I put $org into an array together with $count?

Like this example array:

```
$myArray = @{
  1="SampleOrg";
  2="AnotherSampleOrg"
}
```

Another example:

```
$myArray = @{
  $count="$org";
  $count="$org"
}
```

Example foreach:

```
$count=0;get-organization | foreach {$count++; $org = $_.Name.ToString();write-host $count  -nonewline;write-host " $org"}
$answer = read-host "Select 1-$count"
```

The above will display:

```
1 SampleOrg
2 AnotherSampleOrg

Select 1-2:
```

What I would like to do afterwards is to put the array to use in a switch.

Example:

```
switch ($answer)
   {
     1 {$org=myArray[1]} #<-- or whatever that corresponds to "SampleOrg"
     2 {$org=myArray[2]} #<-- or whatever that corresponds to "AnotherSampleOrg"
   }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but IMO you just need to add a `$myArray.Add($count, $org)` to your `foreach`-loop. EDIT: And you have to initialize your array somewhere before the loop: `$myArray = @{}`

Comment: Your solution was working superb!
`$myArray = @{};$count=0;get-organization | foreach {$count++; $org = $_.Name.ToString();write-host $count  -nonewline;write-host " $org";$myArray.Add($count, $org)}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to initialize your hashtable somewhere before the loop:

```
$myArray = @{}
```

and add a

```
$myArray.Add($count, $org)
```

to your foreach-loop.

EDIT: For the discussion about hastable/array see the whole thread ;) I just kept the name of the variable from the original posting

Comment: End-result: 
`$myArray = @{};$count=0;get-organization | foreach {$count++; $org = $_.Name.ToString();write-host $count  -nonewline;write-host " $org";$myArray.Add($count, $org)}`

Comment: `$myArray = @{}` is not an array

Comment: Hashtables is a type of array. (Associative arrays)

Comment: Hashtables are a type of collection, but not a type of Array.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're confusing arrays and Hashtables. Arrays are ordered, and indexed by an numeric value. Hashtables are associative, and indexed by any value that has equality defined.

This is array syntax

```
$arr = @(1,2,3)
```

and this is Hashtable syntax

```
$ht = @{red=1;blue=2;}
```

For your question, the following will work

```
$orgs = @(get-organization | % { $_.Name })
```

this will create a 0 based array, mapping int -> OrgName, so

```
$orgs[$answer]
```

will get the correct name. Or if you're using 1 based indexing

```
$orgs[$answer-1]
```

Note, I removed the switch, as there's no reason for it.

Comment: won't that create an array with a nested hash table instead of the opposite?

Comment: @JNK - yes, exactly. As the index seems to be an integer, an array is the most apprpriate data structure

Comment: gotcha.  The $answer index threw me off - $answer is an int not a key!  It looks like he wants to use a 1-based index too, so he should look out for the 0.

Comment: In the posted solution there is no prefix number, i.e 1 SampleOrg
Also, when I get the value of $orgs[1] I get Name and Value and not a single variable.

Comment: If the $answer=1 which corresponds to AnotherSampleOrg
Then in the switch case: 1 {$org=orgs[$answer]} this will set $orgs to:

Name             Value
----             -----
SampleOrg        AnotherSampleOrg

But I want to be set to only AnotherSampleOrg.